# c# search data on gridview error in SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to find the data 'surti' in the textbox and I get an error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'surti%'' at line 1

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection cmd;
            cmd = koneksi;
            cmd.Open();
            MySqlCommand sql = new MySqlCommand("Select * from pelanggan where nama_pelanggan like %'" +textBox4.Text+"%'",cmd);
            MySqlDataAdapter ql = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql);
            DataTable tb = new DataTable();
            ql.Fill(tb);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tb;
        }
```

Comment: You have `%'`.  That is not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: You have an error in your query near `like`, this `%'` should be `'%`